# Tomcat, WELD 3, CDI 2, WeldTerminalListener

Tags: tomcat, listener, cdi, weld

Trying to set up a maven web project with CDI 2.0 which should run on Tomcat 8.5. So I have to install the jboss WELD 3.

[What is the relation between Weld, CDI and Java EE versions?](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#9)

With the POM declaration out of here (only "weld-servlet-core")...

[WELD - POM declaration (docs.jboss.org)](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html/environments.html#weld-servlet)

I get an Error with the "WeldTerminalListener", declared in the web.xml like that:

```
<!-- This listener should always be the last registered listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

ERROR: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener

---

If I use the following POM declaration it works fine:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

---

weld-servlet (without "-core") 3 is only available as alpha. The Version 2 is not CDI 2.0 able.

So which dependency in the POM do I need, to get it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weld 3 has changed some artifacts names. It's the `shaded` artifacts which have changed, see [this part of documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html_single/#weld_2_to_3_migration).

Namely, in Weld 2 `weld-servlet` was the shaded version of this JAR so the equivalent in Weld 3 is [`weld-servlet-shaded`](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jboss.weld.servlet%22%20AND%20a%3A%22weld-servlet-shaded%22).

In your case you can be using either this shaded version (`org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet-shaded`) or the core version (`org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet-core`).

As for the class of the listener, you can [check yourself on GH](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/3.0.3.Final/modules/web/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/module/web/servlet/WeldTerminalListener.java), but the story is it was altered as well (say hello to package clash in JDK 9+).
It is now:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldTerminalListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

*Weld documentation (for 3.0.3.Final) has faulty information on this.*
I'll make sure it's corrected for next version (thanks for pointing this out).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the version 3.x of the ***weld-servlet-core*** library, it seems that the actual location of the class is different. After exploring the library ***jar*** file, I've found that the full name of the class is as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldTerminalListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Siliarus answer is more detailed, so I will accept his answer